# Storing installation files in Version Control to automate dev machine setup

Tags: git, version-control, executable, binaryfiles

There is much out there on storing binaries in version control, but all the questions out there seem to refer to binaries built from the code also stored in version control.

In a repo I've just set up, it has all build/config files for a Virtual Machine, such that a team member can install a couple of programs, run a couple of commands, and be ready to develop with the pulled code.

I would like to add the executables for the VM and dev environment so that a dev has everything the moment once they do a pull.

How do I do this?

Comment: How big is this going to be?  I have a blanket rule on my projects that no artifact bigger than 1MB (arbitrary) may be committed, because cloning large repos is a total pain.  My personal preference would be to host the binaries elsewhere, and have an "init" script in your repo which pulls everything down on demand.

Comment: Right now, Virtualbox and Vagrant. So not arbitrary size, but not terrible. The goal is to make bringing on other developers to our process as streamlined as possible.

Comment: Why would you want to include VirtualBox and Vagrant binaries in your repository? Will you update these when new versions are released? What about users on 32-bit machines (assuming you commit the 64-bit versions)? On other operating systems? Do these packages' licenses *allow you* to redistribute them? There is no good reason to include these in your repository, and there are tons of good reasons not to.

Comment: It is like I said, a way for the devs to have access to all they need to get a project running and they would be onetime downloads. Clone a repository locally, you have everything you need, no offsite links, no software differences. The question however, was for non-code based binaries in general.

Comment: That makes an awful lot of assumptions, some of which I mentioned in my previous comment. It also assumes that developers don't already have VirtualBox and Vagrant installed. I don't see any good reason to bundle things with your source code that aren't specific to your project, and these two certainly are not. And there is also the size issue that Oliver mentioned.

Comment: It really isn't an assumption, I know exactly what the devs would have and not have, that's why I have the idea. And you are correct in that ideally VC would be used only for the source. However, other size, I'm not finding a reason to not do this.

Comment: Depends all on the feasibility on your side. Never discuss with purists, if you want to get work done. NEVER. EVER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to add the executable for the VM and dev environment so that a developer has everything the moment once they do a pull.

This is a very valid request, which participates to the overall goal of a configuration management process: being able to replicate a build consistently, in the exact same condition that build was done in the first time.

But this wouldn't be addressed by putting executable directly into a source control.
You would do it by *declaring* those executable in a text file, and letting a third-party framework reinstall those executable for you.

That is exactly what **[Docker](https://www.docker.com/)** is all about: lightweight VM with images which can be built on top of other images (meaning you record only the delta of what you need for your environment)

You would put in your source Git repo a Dockerfile to **declare** what you need:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
RUN apt-get update

## MYSQL
RUN apt-get install -y -q mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev

## RUBY
RUN apt-get install -y -q ruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev rubygems1.9.1 irb1.9.1 build-essential libopenssl-ruby1.9.1 libssl-dev zlib1g-de
```

And you would `docker build` it.
You would have an Ubuntu 12.04 with the exact ruby you would need (in the case of that example).

See more at "[Docker: Git for deployment](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2013/08/28/docker-git-for-deployment)".

> Docker is to deployment as Git is to development

- Docker would push images in its own "image repo cloud",
- while you would push your sources (including your Dockerfile, which *declares* what you need in term of execution environment) to your Git source repo hosting service.

You keep both items (sources vs executable) separate.
Sources are best suited to a *declarative* approach.

Comment: This is an interesting answer, but I'm not sure that it's what the OP is looking for. After all, Vagrant works in precisely the same way: create a `Vagrantfile`, commit that to your repository, and run `vagrant up`. But Vagrant and VirtualBox need to be installed on the host machine for this to work, and those binaries are the ones being asked about. The analog here would be to put the Docker installer into the repository as well as its `Dockerfile`, so that developers don't have to do manually install anything. I wouldn't advise this (and I've said as much in the question comments).

Comment: @Chris "and those binaries are the ones being asked about": I am not so sure about that. You don't need those or Docker to replicate an environment. They can be installed separately. You only need the declaration file which will enable a Docker to rebuild your environment. When you are in that environment (be it done through Vagrant and VirtualBox, or through Docker), you don't care about those Ops Tools. You only care that the components you need to run your program are the exact one you need. That is where a declarative approach is well-suited to be stored in a source control.

Comment: I'm not arguing against your answer; I think it's a good approach. But the question says the user would like to "add the executables for the VM and dev environment", and the OP clarifies in the comments that these are "Virtualbox and Vagrant". I read that as wanting to include something like `VirtualBox_installer.msi` or `vagrant.deb` directly in the repository. Perhaps I've misunderstood. And in fact your statement that "you don't need those or Docker to replicate an environment" is part of the reason that I argue against including them.

Comment: @Chris true, I don't know myself what exact components the OP wants. We'll have to wait for a feedback.

Comment: Chris is correct. The main goal is to streamline the entire process, from the moment the developer is provisioned their computer. Ideally these tools would be included on the new computer, but that is not always the case.  In Linux I would distribute an install script, but I'm trying to account for Windows developers.

Comment: @nobrandheroes I confirm: Docker is the way, even on Windows (https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-6-docker-dev-environments.html). You simply don't store a tool in a *source* control, especially a distributed one you have to clone around.